# jquery live, click and remove

Tags: jquery

I'm getting myself mixed up with this jQuery code, so I hope some one can help!
To explain: The user clicks on a link, the default action is prevented. An AJAX call is made to create a form with a text input field which is given focus. In a simple situation, when the user focusses away from the field the form is submitted and a redirect happens server-side. I'm trying to work out a cancel function. I want the user to be able to re-click the original link to remove the text input and stop the form from submitting. At the moment, although the input field is removed, the form is still submitted, presumably because the focus is removed from it.

I realise that I can't use the toggle() method because I need to be able to bind live() due to the new elements that are created.

Any ideas?!

```
$('.add_tag').live('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); 

               $.post($.baseurl+'messages/add_tag', function(data) {
                  $('.user_tags ul').prepend(data).hide().slideDown();
                  $('#new_tag').focus();

                  $('.add_tag').click( function(e){
                      e.preventDefault();
                      if($('#new_tag').is(':visible')) {
                            // remove it
                            $('#new_tag').slideUp().remove();
                        }
                        return false;
                  });
                      // when the focus moves, automatically add the tag
                      $('#new_tag').blur(function(){ 
                         // send the data to be processed
                         $('form[name="add_tag"]').submit();
                      });
               }); 
    });
```

Comment: Have you got a html snippet i can test on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text box is going to lose focus prior to the click action of the cancel button.  Because of this, it's too late to cancel the submit.  One way of getting around this would be to put the submit on a slight delay and then check for a cancel flag before actually submitting.  Something like this (untested):

```
var submitCanceled=false;

$('#new_tag').blur(function(){ 
   setTimeout(function(){
      // send the data to be processed
      if(!submitCanceled){
         $('form[name="add_tag"]').submit();
      }

      submitCanceled=false;
   },1000);
});

$('#cancel_button').click(function(){
   // ...
   stubmitCanceled=true;
   // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented something based on this and it works great using a delay.